# Create a Search Bar with a Text box for a datagrid Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am using Visual Basic 2010 and am trying to create a datagrid where I can view data from my Sql Server database.

I have the datagrid setup and importing the data from SQL Server, but I am now trying to create on the form something where the user can type into a text box a value, and select a column header from a drop box to pull up a the desired rows.

So I want to be able to type into the Text Box "John" and select in the drop box "Names"

and this would pull up all rows with "John" in column "Names"

Seems simple, but so far I've built everything in the form with just drag and drop from the toolbox so I'm having trouble understanding where to type in backend code for something like this.

Any advice for how this should be approached, or even where I should put code for this would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code on search button click

```
DataTable dt = GetData();
            if (ds.SelectedIndex != -1 && txtFieldValue.Text != "")
            {
                string search = ds.SelectedItem.Text + "=" + txtFieldValue.Text;
                dg.Datasource =  dt.Select(search);
                dg.Databind();
            }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble personalizing this code to fit in mine. "txtfieldvalue" is supposed to be the name of my text box i want to type in right? Do i need to rename the "datatable" "datasource" and "databind" to match my own set ups? This will be my first time doing my own coding, so I'm having trouble with this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hay i have given example you have to change as per your varibale name. You have to set ur method for get data from database. dg = datagrid or gridview.... datasource is property of datagrid or gridview for set data source and databind is method to bind data to gridview or datagrid.  hope you will get idea....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use keyup event with jquery/javascript and update data there is no other way to update data with out any event.